# Slightly different before for `bg` command in zsh vs. bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Today I observed a strange behavior I am hoping I can get some direction on.

### Here's what I'm doing...

With at least one process already running in background, I interrupt (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>) the foreground process and then place it in the background with `bg`.

#### Here are the results in `zsh`:

```
$ some-long-running-command
^Z
zsh: suspended  some-long-running-command
$ bg
[2]  - continued  some-long-running-command
$ jobs
[1]  + running    other-command-previously-run
[2]  - running    some-long-running-command
$
```

#### And here's what it looks like in `bash`:

```
$ other-command-previously-run &
[1] 12345
$ some-long-running-command
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 some-long-running-command
$ bg
[2]+ some-long-running-command &
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 other-command-previously-run &
[2]+  Running                 some-long-running-command &
$
```

So why does `bash` keep the process placed in background with `bg` as the "current" process (indicated by "+" which will be resumed if `fg` is run), while `zsh` sets the "other" process as current? I can't find any documentation suggesting the behavior would be different... Interestingly if you do several `fg` + `^Z` + `bg` in `zsh`, the "current" process selection will "flip flop".

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: What version of zsh and what platform? I cannot reproduce this behavior with zsh 4.3.2 on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this behaviour in `bash` and `zsh`.

My TL;DR answer: the behaviour you see in `bash` is documented. The behaviour you see in `zsh` is not (that I've found), and I have a theory, which might be wrong.

---

**Bash**:

The [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Basics), section 7, "Job Control Basics" describes the behaviour of the builtin `bg`:

> The symbols ‘%%’ and ‘%+’ refer to the shell's notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or started in the background.

Thus, from the point of view of `bash`, the *current job* is the *last job* either stopped in foreground or started in the background. This explains the behaviour noticed in the question:

> So why does bash keep the process placed in background with bg as the "current" process

---

**ZSH**:
I can't explain this for `zsh`. The [`man zshmisc` page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshmisc), under section `JOBS`, explains what `zsh` means by the `+` and `-` in `jobs`:

> %% Current job.
> %+ Equivalent to ‘%%’.
> %- Previous job.

It does *not*, however, explain what effect `bg`, `fg` and `^Z` have on the processes in terms of relegating them to `previous` or `current`.

My *theory*, which I've yet to verify by pestering the nice folks over in `irc.freenode.net#zsh`, is that `zsh` uses a "current-process stack"; `bg` pushes the `current` process to the end of the queue. This can be seen when playing with three processes thus:

```
simont@charmander ~/repositories/SOTesting/bg
  $ one.sh&                                                                                 [1:52:41]
[1] 98369

simont@charmander ~/repositories/SOTesting/bg
  $ two.sh&                                                                                 [1:52:49]
[2] 99293

simont@charmander ~/repositories/SOTesting/bg
  $ three.sh                                                                                [1:52:51]
^Z
[3]  + 973 suspended  three.sh

simont@charmander ~/repositories/SOTesting/bg
  $ jobs                                                                                    [1:52:55]
[1]    running    one.sh
[2]  - running    two.sh
[3]  + suspended  three.sh

simont@charmander ~/repositories/SOTesting/bg
  $ bg                                                                                      [1:52:57]
[3]  - 973 continued  three.sh

simont@charmander ~/repositories/SOTesting/bg
  $ jobs                                                                                    [1:52:59]
[1]    running    one.sh
[2]  + running    two.sh
[3]  - running    three.sh
```

As we can see here, `one` and `two` are pushed down on the theoretical stack. `three`, being executed last(?) is the `current process`, denoted by the `+` from the `jobs` output.
After `three` is suspended, it is still the current process, but after `bg`, it is pushed to the `previous` process and `two`, being the "top" process in the "stack" becomes the new `current` process.

This, however, is conjecture; like I said, I haven't got documented proof of this, and, honestly, the `man zsh*` pages are slightly complicated; I may have missed something.